# cuda profiler nvprof not showing surface/texture read or write

Tags: cuda, textures, profiler, nsight, geometry-surface

I'm trying to profile a kernel that uses 3D surfaces to read and write to 3D cudaArrays.

Unfortunately nvprof shows absolutely nothing for any texture reads or writes or cache activity etc.

It is also showing very poor memory access etc.

The application works perfectly so the surface read and write calls are obviously working.

Any ideas on this? Perhaps nvprof cant show surface activity yet?

Comment: It isn't at all obvious what you are asking here. Could you explain exactly what you would like to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVIDA profilers do not currently supported analysis of surface or texture accesses.

Comment: Just to clarify, that explains why I see nothing for the surface acesses which is the question I was asking in my original post. So again. Thanks Greg.